# std in conditional compilation

Tags: rust, compilation

`#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]`

Does the "std" above reflect the rust standard library or the std feature defined in the cargo.toml for a given crate?

Also, for many of the dependencies, default features is set to false, but no optional features are given, i [Read](https://dev.to/rimutaka/cargo-features-explained-with-examples-194g) that

```
rusoto_dynamodb = { version = "0.43.0", default-features = false, optional = true }
```

would be transformed to

```
rusoto_dynamodb = { version = "0.43.0", default-features = true }
```

Is this the case with the dependencies used in substrate, i.e. would std (default feature) be used by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing magical about the `std` feature, it's more of an idiomatic label Rust devs use to signal that code that use it will make use of the standard library.

As for your question about default features and the `optional` attribute, I think you're likely better off reading the rust documentation. In short, the two are unrelated. Using `"default-features": false` means that the crate is compiled without enabling the default feature; marking the crate `optional` means that it is itself only compiled if there is a feature that enables it, that it's opt-in.

Answer (score 4):

There does not exist a `std` feature in rust. It refers to the `std` feature defined in the Cargo.toml file.

The `std` feature enables additional code that is used by the node 'client' - the code that runs the runtime (i.e. the code that does consensus, networking, transaction pool etc.). The runtime itself does not use any `std` code as it is all compiled to wasm (which is no_std)

Comment: I think i'm missing something here. You say that the runtime itself does not use any std (in terms of feature) code, however, all pallets depend on frame_system which is apart of the std feature (See this link to template pallet cargo.toml
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/Cargo.toml#L29), how can this be?

Comment: The frame_system pallet mostly has `no_std` functionality, but also has some functionality that makes use of `std::*` and these bits are put behind a feature that the frame_system crate defines in Cargo.toml called "std". The wasm code isn't able to call any `std` fn directly (but could call that functionality indirectly via a host function).