# Testing for emojis in a Substrate Pallet

Tags: pallet

I have a pallet I'm working on that wants to deal with emojis (allowing emojis to be submitted, stored, etc).  i found Rust crate [unic_emoji_char](https://docs.rs/unic-emoji-char/latest/unic_emoji_char/) which I think would help greatly, but can't get it to work in a pallet.  I'm assuming it has something to do with `std`.

To the cargo.toml I add:
`unic-emoji-char = { version = "0.9.0", default-features = false }`

And in std:
   `"unic-emoji-char/std",`

Snips of errors when I `cargo test`:

```
error: failed to select a version for `unic-emoji-char`.
...
the package `pallet-rmrk-core` depends on `unic-emoji-char`, with features: `std` but `unic-emoji-char` does not have these features.
```

Guessing I just can't use this library, but are there any suggestions for how to do emoji-checking with Rust/Substrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std` feature is not something that works out of box. It is just a convention that crate authors may or may not stick to.

As you can see, there is no `std` feature in Cargo.toml of `unic-emoji-char` [here](https://github.com/open-i18n/rust-unic/blob/41cd2b01e2e51a2b8d7d32fd13b14c0c092ac014/unic/emoji/char/Cargo.toml).

Apart from that, compiling code to a runtime implies using the `no_std` environment (see [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/why-do-we-need-cfg-attrnotfeature-std-no-std) for more details) and the crate in question does not seem to declare that in its lib.rs.